# html/javascript textbox issue

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

When you get out of focus of a textbox and you press letter on the keyboard it automatically goes in focus with the letter typed in. Is there a code that could do that? Thanks. Much appreciated.

Comment: My apologies, I thought that said textbook. My I'm getting old.

Answer (score 0):

To focus in your textbox

```
document.formname.textboxname.focus();
```